# How to create a custom sitemap of multiple subdomains?

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap, google-search, yoast

how can I achieve a certain well structured layout in the Google search results as presented below? I am working with multiple Wordpress instances on several sub domains (not a multisite). Google does not get along with the sitemap structure so all sites are scattered around. Any ideas?

In the search results it should look like this (basically like any other well structured sitemap):

```
MAINPAGE.COM
(Meta text)

---- SUB.MAINPAGE.COM
---- SUB.MAINPAGE.COM
---- SUB.MAINPAGE.COM
```

I messed around with Toast but I did not reach any results.

Answer (score 0):

Messed around with Yoast? You just need to install Yoast on all instances. Submit the sitemaps generated by Yoast from all sites to Search Console.

> Positioning the results in Google SERPs is not driven by sitemap. It
> is driven by Google's algorithmic analysis and rankings. For one
> search query, it is possible that Google finds a page from Instance B
> better than instance C page or other site etc.

Under Google Search Console > Indexing > check the issues you're having with indexing. Do this for each instance property OR if you've only one property for ALL sub-domains, just check the Indexing/Coverage issues.

---

**Additional Notes:**

Wordpress 5+ comes with built-in sitemap functionality. If you're having issues with Yoast sitemap generation, try that as a fallback. Yoast sitemaps are better than built-in ones. Anyway. Submit them for each WordPress instances to Search Console to let Google discover pages from your submitted sitemaps.

Plus. If you want Google to analyze pages from all of your sub-domains, verify Search Console via DNS property. It acknowledges Google to explore through all main site and its sub-domains under the same property including https & http versions.